# Akamai forward caching dynamic content like web services

Tags: akamai

I have a general question about what Akamai can provide for web services. We are looking to develop a web service and our web service application is hosted in the US, but we would expect that our web service can be accessed from across the globe. I would like to know if 1) Akamai caches dynamic content like web services, and 2) can Akamai provide some better performance if it can cache a web service.

```
Such as a .ASMX endpoint where there is nothing static about it. The content is 100% dynamic as it fetches data from the back-end like a database and returns it. I’m wondering if Akamai would apply here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Akamai can definitely be used for web services, it all comes down to your own decisions about how long content should be valid before the server (your service) needs to supply a new version of the content. In simple terms Akamai are only doing what http will do for you anyway, if you set cache control headers for the resources you serve from your API then clients will look at those headers and not request new copies of resources if you've told them that the resource is valid for 10s/10m/10h, etc.

Of course in practice Akamai does a lot more than that, firstly they have over 200k servers globally so your content will sit close to your users wherever they are in the world meaning if that content is still fresh your users will get it very quickly (from a server near them, not from your servers). Secondly, if they do need to request content from you, they do it over a super-optimised network which monitors itself to ensure the quickest route across the globe is taken. If you're concerned about them serving stale content you can even have every request go to your service to check if there's a more up to date copy, eg by using eTags.

The whole thing is highly configurable as well as being extensible from your end using custom headers to instruct their network how you want to deal with different content and endpoints. This is just a quick overview, they can do a lot more as well, definitely worth a look.